# How to create tags that are different, which are unique to the blogs in django wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

Hello I am following this tutorial, https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html# and I am on the tags portion.

Question I have is, how do I create tags thats different for each application.
I have two apps, LibBlog and libnewsblog.

If i create a tag for Blog called School, I want it to only search Blog.
Same thing for Libnews. Right now When I click on the Tag "School" it shows up posts from both LibBlog and LibNewsBlog.

Comment: Hey. Can you update your question with a bit more detail, when you say 'each application' do you mean each Site? Or do you mean a branch of pages?

Comment: I meant each site. I have one for libnews blog and one for libblog

Answer (score 0):

In the section where it describes the code for `BlogTagIndexPage` you will need to ensure that your `context['blogpages']` only returns pages from the current site.

- To get the current site you can use the [`Site.find_for_request`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Site.find_for_request) static method, you will need to import `Site` from `wagtail.core.models`.
- The `Site` will have an attribute [`root_page`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Site.root_page) which is the first page within that site (e.g. the home page).
- To filter a page query by being a descendant (not just direct child but children and their children etc) you can use the [`descendant_of` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/queryset_reference.html#wagtail.core.query.PageQuerySet.descendant_of)

### Example

- Putting this all together we now have a revised version of your `BlogTagIndexPage` which will only show `BlogPage` objects based on the `Site` for the current request.
- We have replaced the line `blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)` with a query that will first show pages within the current site only.
- We have added the line `site = Site.find_for_request(request)` to determine the current `Site`.

```py
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Site

# ... other imports

class BlogTagIndexPage(Page):

    def get_context(self, request):
        site = Site.find_for_request(request) # added to determine current site

        # Filter by tag
        tag = request.GET.get('tag')
        # blogpages = BlogPage.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)
        blogpages = BlogPage.objects.descendant_of(site.root_page).filter(tags__name=tag) # changed to include only descendants of root page

        # Update template context
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['blogpages'] = blogpages
        return context
```

Comment: Last question I have is for creating Categories. Filter on those category or filter by categories. here is my model.py `class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)`

Comment: [code]@register_snippet
class BlogCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    icon = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image', null=True, blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        ImageChooserPanel('icon'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'blog categories'[/code]

Comment: my blog_page.html is <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
<p class="meta">{{ page.date }}</p>

{% with categories=page.categories.all %}
    {% if categories %}
        <h3>Posted in:</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for category in categories %}
                <li style="display: inline">
                    {% image category.icon fill-32x32 style="vertical-align: middle" %}
                    {{ category.name }}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}

Comment: Hey @soupi I do not fully understand what you are asking sorry, maybe it is better to write a new question on Stack Overflow with this different question about creating categories.